# Custom API Action: Access Request Body

Tags: api, extension, developer

I'm developing a custom API v3 action which is intended to handle a webhook request from Zoom (https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/webhook-reference). Zoom follows REST standards by putting the data inside the request's body (not like the CiviCRM api where you put the data inside a json parameter). So, is there a way to access the request's body from my custom action or custom extension?

Answer (score 2):

This is typically handled by adding a webhook endpoint to your extension.  The Mailchimp extension does this - see [Webhook.php](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/blob/master/CRM/Mailchimp/Page/WebHook.php).

If you've already written your API action, it shouldn't be too tough to use a webhook to grab the data and push to API.

It sounds like maybe you're past this point, but https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/issues/55 is an issue I raised to deal with handling POST data stored as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: This answer won't work. See comments.

---

You can always access $_POST.

There is CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve() - it serves a different purpose but you could also use it, specifying method 'POST'. It's not technically a supported API call though. See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.22.1/CRM/Utils/Request.php#L51

Comment: Yeah, I expected $_POST to work but somehow it gives me a blank array.

Comment: So, $_POST didn't work because it doesn't work for JSON content type. I had to use `file_get_contents('php://input')` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php#answer-18867369)

Comment: Oh I see. It's not specifically that it's JSON, it's that it isn't parsed by php into $_POST because it's not a `param=value&param2=value2` type of http request where content-type would be application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for that nugget of info